# Error: A function expression can't have a name. Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: context){ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am getting this exception while trying to navigate to another page using `Navigator.of(context).push()` :

```
lib/main.dart:20:41: Error: A function expression can't have a name.
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: context){
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:20:68: Error: Not a constant expression.
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: context){
                                                                   ^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:20:66: Error: Non-optional parameters can't have a default value.
Try removing the default value or making the parameter optional.
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: context){
                                                                 ^
lib/main.dart: Error: The argument type 'HomePage Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route<Object>'.***
```

Code :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Are You Present?',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child:
                FlatButton(onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: context){
                      return HomePage();
                    }
                  );
                }, child: Text("Press to Continue")),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code! It is hard to search or copy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to use `Navigator.of(context).push()` :

**Try changing the code inside the `onPressed` with following**

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context){
              return HomePage();
            }
          ));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return Demo();
              },
            ),
          );
```

the builder takes a function as an input and we have provided an anonymous function having parameter as current **context** and we returned the class that we want to push on the stack if the button is pressed.